# Why does adding .fadeIn have this disrupt the behavior?

Tags: jquery, menu

Right now I am creating a menu and am having trouble with this fadeIn command

This is the code:

```
var main = function () {
"use strict";

$('.whoWeAre').addClass('inactive-slide');

$('.nav li:nth-child(1)').click(function () {

    $('.whoWeAre').addClass('inactive-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.welcome').fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

});

$('.nav li:nth-child(2)').click(function () {

    $('.welcome').addClass('inactive-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.whoWeAre').fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide')

});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

it switches what is being displayed, depending on the button clicked. And it works fine without the .fadeIn added. But the second I add it, it seems like the .removeClass('active-slide') or the .addClass('inactive-slide') stop working, as both paragraphs will be displayed after clicking on each of them.

If you'd like to see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/royal_wisdom/z67ummw2/46/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.fadeIn()` puts a `style="display: block;"` on the element which overrides your CSS classes for hiding the element.  So, basically you need to increase the CSS specificity of your CSS rules for hiding the elements.

One way to do that is by adding `!important`:

```
.inactive-slide {
    display: none !important;
}
.active-slide {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1pxndm3e/

Comment: Thank you! I'm just learning now, so all of these simple things are making me pull my hair out

Comment: @RM3 - Yeah, when in doubt go into the DOM inspector and look at what styles are on the element, both directly on the element and via CSS to see why it isn't displaying the way you expect.